# Why does Bruce Eckel says that only objects can be passed into a method in Java?

Tags: java, object, primitive

Here's a quote from Bruce Eckel's book "Thinking in Java":

> The method argument list specifies what information you pass into the
>   method. As you might guess, this information—like everything else in
>   Java—takes the form of objects. So, what you must specify in the
>   argument list are the types of the objects to pass in and the name to
>   use for each one.

I don't get it. I think you can pass primitives to a method (e.g. int) and primitives aren't objects. 
For example:

```
public static int multiply(int x, int y){
    return x * y;
```

This is a method and there are only primitives in it, no objects at all.

Comment: primitives are special case, don't overthink it. Mr Eckel had to mention it few times in his book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author doesn't say that *only* objects can be passed to methods. This quote comes in the context of a chapter called *"Everything is an Object"*. It aims to highlight the object-oriented aspect of the language, but it also includes a section on primitives which explains that they are a special case.

Nevertheless, what you say about the method taking only primitive types is still correct but this is implicitly covered by the "Special case: primitive types" section.